# how to use session in second page as a directory name in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$videopath = 'video/$_SESSION['username']';
$videoExts = array('webm'=>'video/webm','mp4'=>'video/mp4','mpeg'=>'video/mp4','ogv'=>'video/ogv');
$directory = "/video";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.html");

if ($handle = opendir($videopath)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $info =PATHINFO($file);
   $ext = strtolower($info['extension']);
   $filename = basename($file,".$ext");


    if (array_key_exists($ext, $videoExts)) {      
?>
```

i am taking `$_SESSION['username']` from log in page

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

i am also creating a folder name with

```
mkdir("video/$username");
```

but code give error like this

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'username' (T_STRING) in    C:\xampp\htdocs\akash\vidsite\mychannel.php on line 38

please help how to use session

Comment: Hi Akash, please look at the second line of php code: `$videopath = 'video/$_SESSION['username']';` which should be `$videopath = 'video/' . $_SESSION['username'];`

Answer (score 1):

`$videopath = 'video/$_SESSION['username']';`

has to be

```
$videopath = 'video/' . $_SESSION['username'];
```

or

```
$videopath = "video/{$_SESSION['username']}";
```

Because you're breaking the quotes in your string.

Comment: $store = 'video/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/'.$f_newfile;

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$videopath = 'video/$_SESSION['username']';
```

Should be:

```
$videopath = 'video/' . $_SESSION['username'];
```

because `.` is the concatenation character in PHP

Comment: $store = 'video/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/'.$f_newfile;

Comment: how to write this? please help